# Validaciones en Java

Tags: java, validación

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase donde nos mandan validar lo que se mete por teclado. Os dejo mi enunciado, os digo el fallo que me da y pregunta.

o   Métodos estáticos pedirNombre, pedirNif y activarDorsal sin argumentos que solicitan al usuario que introduzca cada uno de los datos de un corredor y devuelven tal dato validado (desde cada uno de estos métodos se llamará a cada uno de los métodos validadores).

o   Métodos estáticos validarNombre, validarNif y validarDorsal que reciban como argumento cada uno de los posibles datos del corredor y lo validan según las condiciones.

· El nombre será válido siempre que tenga una longitud igual o superior a 3 caracteres e igual o inferior a 15 caracteres, que empiece por mayúsculas y admita espacios.

· El nif del corredor será válido siempre que esté compuesto por 8 dígitos y una letra que ha de corresponderse con tales números por el algoritmo del “módulo 23”.

· Para validar el dorsal se deberá comprobar si ya está activo.

Ahora mismo estoy con el de validar nombre donde nos piden que la longitud esté entre 3 y 15 caracteres, que empiece por mayus y que pueda contener espacios.

Por ahora tengo esto, y tanto nombreMayus  que me da error de que no es una variable estática y el while que intento hacer me da error de que es una expresión illegal. Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma mejor de que esas tres características que pidan se pueda hacer de una manera más simple? o debe ser así?

```
public static void validarNombre(){
    String nombreMayus = nombre.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + nombre.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    try{
    while(nombreMayus.length()=>3 && nombreMayus.length()=<15){

    System.out.println("Ingresado correctamente");

    }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    }
```

Comment: No es correcto lo que estás haciendo. Por método validador yo entiendo un método que **recibe como parámetro un dato** para validarlo según los criterios enunciados en la pregunta. El método retornaría `true` si el dato fuese válido o `false` si no lo fuese. Otra cosa que podría hacerse sería corregir el dato, pero eso ya escaparía del alcance de lo que se está pidiendo. En cuanto a la forma de validar, pueden haber varias posibilidades... dado que es un ejercicio todo depende de lo que se te permita usar en él.

Comment: Buenas. Substring te crea una subcadena de texto con los carácteres que quieras, pero en el segundo caso le estás diciendo que te cree una subcadena del carácter 2 solamente, no desde el carácter 2 al final del nombre. Debería ser `nombre.substring(1,nombre.length()).toLowerCase()`. Y debes comprobar que nombre no sea NULL o menor que 1 o saldrá error.

Después estás poniendo un while en el que si se cumplen tus condiciones pones un mensaje de correcto, pero nunca sales del while así que es un bucle infinito, debería ser un IF. ADEMAS has puesto `=< 15` cuando es `<= 15`

Comment: Sigue dandome el mismo error...

Comment: Que noooo, ese método tal y como lo tienes ahora no podrá ser nunca un validador. Un método que valida algo lo debe recibir desde el exterior, en parámetro, y hacer la validación de eso que recibe, indicando si es válido o no. Te advierto de que vas a suspender tu ejercicio como sigas así. Lee el enunciado: *Métodos estáticos validarNombre, validarNif y validarDorsal **que reciban como argumento cada uno de los posibles datos** del corredor y lo validan según las condiciones.*

Comment: Tengo que hacer el Scanner en el validador?

Answer (score 1):

El enunciado del método que intentas escribir dice lo siguiente:

> Métodos estáticos validarNombre, validarNif y validarDorsal **que
> reciban como argumento cada uno de los posibles datos** del corredor y
> lo validan según las condiciones.

O sea, un método validador **debe recibir en parámetro el dato** y validarlo según las exigencias indicadas.

Generalmente el método devolvería un booleano verdadero o falso según el resultado de la evaluación.

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo que cumple las exigencias enunciadas para validar el nombre. Yo he usado tres ternarios para evaluar cada condición (si no se permiten los ternarios todavía por ser un curso, los puedes cambiar por `if`. Los ternarios ahorran varias líneas de código, aportando simplicidad).

Nótese que el  método es *null safe*. Es muy importante la verificación de nulos, si no se hace el código hará un crash ante posibles valores nulos.

Este sería el método de validación:

```
public static boolean validarNombre(String mNombre){
    boolean checkStatus=false;
    
    /*Verificamos que no sea null*/ 
    if(mNombre != null){
        /* 1ª Condición: que la letra inicial sea mayúscula*/
        boolean isFirstUpper=Character.isUpperCase(mNombre.charAt(0));

        /* 2ª Condición: que el tamaño sea >= 3 y <= 15*/
        int stringSize=mNombre.length();
        boolean isValidSize=(stringSize >= 3 && stringSize <= 15);

        /* 3ª Condición: que contenga al menos un espacio*/
        boolean isSpaced=mNombre.contains(" ");

        /* Verificamos que las tres condiciones son verdaderas*/
        checkStatus= ( (isFirstUpper==true)  && (isFirstUpper && isValidSize &&  isSpaced) );
    }
    /*Devolvemos el estado de la validación*/
    return checkStatus;
}
```

Varias pruebas desde el `main`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String elNombre="Pedro Suarez";       
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));
    elNombre="Pedro Suarez Más de Quince";
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));
    elNombre="pedrito suarez";
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));
    elNombre="12";
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));
    elNombre="PedroSinEspacio";
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));       
    elNombre=null;
    System.out.println(validarNombre(elNombre));       

}
```

**Salida:**

```
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

---

#### Demostración en línea

Aquí puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/REP78044)</kbd>** del código en  línea y hacer pruebas sobre ella.

Espero te sea de utilidad.